# Python: Navigate to portable devices directory (Windows 7)

Tags: python, windows, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to solve [a question I have created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21381652/python-find-record-time-of-mp4-movie?noredirect=1#comment32343857_21381652) about how to read the recorded date of the videos I took with a windows phone. It seems that the creation date are overwritten when the files are "sync" to my computer.

I'm trying to get around this by looking at the files in the phone directly. So I need to access to

```
"Computer\Windows Phone\Phone\Pictures\Camera Roll"
```

My problem is that I can only get `os.chdir()` to work on paths that has `C://` as root

Any suggestions?

### Update

I tried to place and run a file that prints the current directory.
Which gave me the result

```
C:\Users\<myUser~1.COM>\AppData\Local\Temp\WPDNSE\{<a lot of numbers and dashes>}
```

Comment: Did you try UNC format, e.g. "\\server\share\filename"?
Check also what you get from `os.getcwd()`

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Windows Phone paths in particular, but you should be able to figure out the "real" path by using the Windows file explorer to look at the properties of a file or folder. Right-click, choose Properties and look for a Location field.

Note that some "folders", such as the ones under "Libraries", are actually XML files pointing to multiple other locations.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the phone is connect via MTP.

[How to access an MTP USB device with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11161747/how-to-access-an-mtp-usb-device-with-python)

could help then.

[EDIT] They mentioned calibre there. The source code of calibre mabye already contain functions for getting file informations on mobile devices.