# What's the best way to get video metadata from a video file in ASP.Net MVC using C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, video, ffmpeg, metadata

I've been searching on Google and StackOverflow for a good couple of hours. There seems to be a lot of similar questions on StackOverflow but they are all about 3-5 years old.

Is using FFMPEG still the best way these days to pull metadata from a video file in a .NET web application? And if so, what's the best C# wrapper out there?

I've tried MediaToolkit, MediaFile.dll without any luck. I saw ffmpeg-csharpe but that looks like it hasn't been touched in a few years.

I haven't found any current data on this subject. Is the ability to pull metadata from a video built into the latest version of .NET now?

I'm basically looking for any direction at this point.

I should add that whatever I use could be invoked thousands of times per hour so it will need to be efficient.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Have a look at `MediaInfo` project (http://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo)

it gets extensive information about most media types, and the library is bundled with a c# helper class which is easy to use.

You can download the library and helper class for windows from here:

http://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo/Download/Windows *(DLL without installer)*

The helper class is located at `Developers\Source\MediaInfoDLL\MediaInfoDLL.cs`, simply add it to your project and copy the `MediaInfo.dll` to your bin.

**Usage**

you can obtain information by requesting specific parameter from the library, Here is a sample:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main(string[] Args)
{
    var mi = new MediaInfo();
    mi.Open(@"video path here");

    var videoInfo = new VideoInfo(mi);
    var audioInfo = new AudioInfo(mi);
     mi.Close();
}

public class VideoInfo 
{
    public string Codec { get; private set; }
    public int Width { get; private set; }
    public int Heigth { get; private set; }
    public double FrameRate { get; private set; }
    public string FrameRateMode { get; private set; }
    public string ScanType { get; private set; }
    public TimeSpan Duration { get; private set; }
    public int Bitrate { get; private set; }
    public string AspectRatioMode { get; private set; }
    public double AspectRatio { get; private set; }

    public VideoInfo(MediaInfo mi)
    {
        Codec=mi.Get(StreamKind.Video, 0, "Format");
        Width = int.Parse(mi.Get(StreamKind.Video, 0, "Width"));
        Heigth = int.Parse(mi.Get(StreamKind.Video, 0, "Height"));
        Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(int.Parse(mi.Get(StreamKind.Video, 0, "Duration")));
        Bitrate = int.Parse(mi.Get(StreamKind.Video, 0, "BitRate"));
        AspectRatioMode = mi.Get(StreamKind.Video, 0, "AspectRatio/String"); //as formatted string
        AspectRatio =double.Parse(mi.Get(StreamKind.Video, 0, "AspectRatio"));
        FrameRate = double.Parse(mi.Get(StreamKind.Video, 0, "FrameRate"));
        FrameRateMode = mi.Get(StreamKind.Video, 0, "FrameRate_Mode");
        ScanType = mi.Get(StreamKind.Video, 0, "ScanType");
    }
}

public class AudioInfo
{
    public string Codec { get; private set; }
    public string CompressionMode { get; private set; }
    public string ChannelPositions { get; private set; }
    public TimeSpan Duration { get; private set; }
    public int Bitrate { get; private set; }
    public string BitrateMode { get; private set; }
    public int SamplingRate { get; private set; }

    public AudioInfo(MediaInfo mi)
    {
        Codec = mi.Get(StreamKind.Audio, 0, "Format");
        Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(int.Parse(mi.Get(StreamKind.Audio, 0, "Duration")));
        Bitrate = int.Parse(mi.Get(StreamKind.Audio, 0, "BitRate"));
        BitrateMode = mi.Get(StreamKind.Audio, 0, "BitRate_Mode");
        CompressionMode = mi.Get(StreamKind.Audio, 0, "Compression_Mode");
        ChannelPositions = mi.Get(StreamKind.Audio, 0, "ChannelPositions");
        SamplingRate = int.Parse(mi.Get(StreamKind.Audio, 0, "SamplingRate"));
    }
}
```

You can easily obtain all information in string format by calling`Inform()`:

```
        var mi = new MediaInfo();
        mi.Open(@"video path here");
        Console.WriteLine(mi.Inform());
        mi.Close();
```

if you need more information about available parameters, you can simply query all of them by calling `Options("Info_Parameters")`:

```
        var mi = new MediaInfo();
        Console.WriteLine(mi.Option("Info_Parameters"));
        mi.Close();
```

Comment: Thank you. With your help I was able to get MediaInfo working in my solution!

Comment: When I try for a cloud video url  it doesn't work. Here is the url: https://vault-development.b-cdn.net/mtk1mtbgrdatqzı0rc00rjywlthcmeetrunb/8cd0e9af15f4baaafe9dfe98ace8b88630f2fa4c-5d85-4273-a21f-f528da321400.mp4

Answer (score 11):

It may be little late...
You can do this with minimal code using the NuGet package of MediaToolKit

For more info get going from here [MediaToolKit](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MediaToolkit/)

Comment: I had issues using MediaInfo and this was much easier. Not sure why the OP didn't want to use it.

Comment: it doesn't seem to be maintained

Answer (score 5):

I suggest you use ffmpeg with Process.Start, the code looks like follows:

```
    private string GetVideoDuration(string ffmpegfile, string sourceFile) {
        using (System.Diagnostics.Process ffmpeg = new System.Diagnostics.Process()) {
            String duration;  // soon will hold our video's duration in the form "HH:MM:SS.UU"
            String result;  // temp variable holding a string representation of our video's duration
            StreamReader errorreader;  // StringWriter to hold output from ffmpeg

            // we want to execute the process without opening a shell
            ffmpeg.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            //ffmpeg.StartInfo.ErrorDialog = false;
            ffmpeg.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            // redirect StandardError so we can parse it
            // for some reason the output comes through over StandardError
            ffmpeg.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

            // set the file name of our process, including the full path
            // (as well as quotes, as if you were calling it from the command-line)
            ffmpeg.StartInfo.FileName = ffmpegfile;

            // set the command-line arguments of our process, including full paths of any files
            // (as well as quotes, as if you were passing these arguments on the command-line)
            ffmpeg.StartInfo.Arguments = "-i " + sourceFile;

            // start the process
            ffmpeg.Start();

            // now that the process is started, we can redirect output to the StreamReader we defined
            errorreader = ffmpeg.StandardError;

            // wait until ffmpeg comes back
            ffmpeg.WaitForExit();

            // read the output from ffmpeg, which for some reason is found in Process.StandardError
            result = errorreader.ReadToEnd();

            // a little convoluded, this string manipulation...
            // working from the inside out, it:
            // takes a substring of result, starting from the end of the "Duration: " label contained within,
            // (execute "ffmpeg.exe -i somevideofile" on the command-line to verify for yourself that it is there)
            // and going the full length of the timestamp

            duration = result.Substring(result.IndexOf("Duration: ") + ("Duration: ").Length, ("00:00:00").Length);
            return duration;
        }
    }
```

May it helps.

Answer (score 4):

ffmpeg also offers a special application [`ffprobe`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html) for reading metadata. We wrote a wrapper for .net and provided a [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Alturos.VideoInfo), you can find it here: [Alturos.VideoInfo](https://github.com/AlturosDestinations/Alturos.VideoInfo)

```cs
PM> Install-Package Alturos.VideoInfo
```

Example:

```cs
var videoFilePath = "myVideo.mp4";

var videoAnalyer = new VideoAnalyzer();
var analyzeResult = videoAnalyer.GetVideoInfo(videoFilePath);
var videoInfo = analyzeResult.VideoInfo;
//videoInfo.Format.Filename = "myVideo.mp4"
//videoInfo.Format.NbStreams = 1
//videoInfo.Format.NbPrograms = 0
//videoInfo.Format.FormatName = "mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2"
//videoInfo.Format.FormatLongName = "QuickTime / MOV"
//videoInfo.Format.StartTime = 0
//videoInfo.Format.Duration = 120 //seconds
//videoInfo.Format.Size = 2088470 //bytes
//videoInfo.Format.BitRate = 139231
//videoInfo.Format.ProbeScore = 100
//videoInfo.Format.Tags["encoder"] = Lavf57.76.100
//videoInfo.Streams[0].CodecType = "video" //Video, Audio
//videoInfo.Streams[0]...
```

Comment: This library was good but now the backing library is no more maintained so this will not work unless the said library is also shipped along with it.

Comment: Yes, I have already noticed that. You can use this source  https://ffbinaries.com/downloads