# How to get the video duration ? ASP.NET MVC 5 C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, video, duration

What is best way to get?

I have a field where user will upload video.

When you click the upload button, come this way in the controller action:

[image]

How to catch the duration? (Marked in red line)

Example:

[image]

Any idea ?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Maybe this helps? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26051273/whats-the-best-way-to-get-video-metadata-from-a-mp4-file-in-asp-net-mvc-using-c

Comment: Did you figured it out. I have the same issue

Comment: @carpics, I did not find out.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Alturos.VideoInfo](https://github.com/AlturosDestinations/Alturos.VideoInfo) to obtain the duration.

Once installed, you do something like this to retrieve the metadata for your video:

```
var videoFilePath = "myVideo.mp4";

var videoAnalyer = new VideoAnalyzer();
var analyzeResult = videoAnalyer.GetVideoInfo(videoFilePath);

if (analyzeResult.Successful)
{
    var videoInfo = analyzeResult.VideoInfo;
}
else
{
    // Error handling here
    System.Console.WriteLine(analyzeResult.ErrorMessage);
}
```

You will find the video duration in

```
videoInfo.Format.Duration
```

Hope this helps!