# Get duration of Video after upload

Tags: c#, asp.net, video, duration

What is best way to get?

I have a field where user will upload video.

When you click the upload button, Video get uploaded. This work perfectly.

I needed the duration of the video from physical path, I tried:

```
using WMPLib;
WindowsMediaPlayer wmp = new WindowsMediaPlayerClass();
IWMPMedia mediaInfo = wmp.newMedia(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/test.mp4"));
double duration = mediaInfo.duration;
```

But its not working, I get error:

> The type 'WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayerClass' has no constructors defined Interop type 'WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayerClass' cannot be embedded.

How to catch the duration?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the best way to get video metadata from a MP4 file in ASP.Net MVC using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26051273/whats-the-best-way-to-get-video-metadata-from-a-mp4-file-in-asp-net-mvc-using-c)

Comment: Refer https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2d095670-9920-44f3-a386-3cfeceeb14c0/c-get-video-duration?forum=csharpgeneral for the solution.

Comment: i tried them but they are not helping me :(

Comment: @irshadjm did you tried to add the `WindowsMediaPlayer` Embedded explicitly by going to properties of that `WMPLib` and setting `Embeded = True`

Comment: You will have to ask Code that is designed to display/process the video for that detail. The filelenght could never be a indicator. And there can be so many alternate tracks of video/audio it might not even be constant for one specific clip. I think it is customary to accept just about "any kind of video", then do conversion to a default format serverside. While doing that you can figure the lenght as a side effect. Having it in one form will also help detecting duplicates (ideally use some checksums for that).

Comment: @irshadjm will the videos uploaded always be `.mp4`?

Comment: @irshadjm nevermind. If always MP4 I would have just told you which part of MP4's **bytes** holds the **duration** (eg: where other programs also check to know duration).

Answer (score 9):

You can use this nuget package:

```
Install-Package Xabe.FFMpeg
```

I'm trying to make easy to use, cross-platform FFmpeg wrapper.

You can find more information about this at [Xabe.FFmpeg](https://xabe.net/product/xabe_ffmpeg/)

```
IMediaInfo mediaInfo = await FFmpeg.GetMediaInfo("videofile.mkv");
var videoDuration = mediaInfo.VideoStreams.First().Duration;
```

More info about getting duration of video file at:
https://ffmpeg.xabe.net/docs.html

Comment: I tried the FFMpeg project, code looks good but couldn't get it to compile, if you have time could you provide a GitHub guide to get it working?

Comment: This project is in .NET Standard 2.0. Maybe this is the problem. According to documentation .NET Standard is supported in .NET Framework above 4.6.1 ([link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/08/14/announcing-net-standard-2-0/)) but not everytime works on it. I'll try to fix the problem. @JeremyThompson if you could, please make issue on github with compilation errors.

Comment: @TomaszŻmuda `VideoInfo` is pending obsoletion, and is being replaced with `MediaInfo`.

Comment: .Get() is not a function of MediaInfo

Comment: @Freerey thanks for editing. Public API was changed a some time ago

Answer (score 2):

With DirectShow.Net wrapper library, you can use the DirectShow API `MediaDet` object. The method `get_StreamLength` is the one that gets the length of the video in seconds, which can be converted into mins/hrs using a deterministic algorithm. To use this API make sure the MPEG-4 dependency has been installed on your operating system.

or you can opt for [Media Info](http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net/en) library for getting information from a video file.

See an implementation using DirectShow.NET wrapper library: [Getting length of video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6215185/getting-length-of-video)

Answer (score 2):

We get the video Durations in many ways are

Method 1: Shell 32 API

Method 2: WMPLib (windows Media Player Library)

Method 3: FFMpeg Wrapper

check the below links

Method 1 and Method 2 Link [get-the-length-of-a-video-in-c#](http://www.levibotelho.com/development/get-the-length-of-a-video-in-c/)

Method 3 Reference Link [video file time duration in ffmpeg](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/58502-how-to-get-video-file-durationtime-using-c%23/)

In this Method used for get video properties and duraion  all these three i was checked previously.it's working fine some custom attriburtes in file properties not show in first 2 Methods.

the Method 3 is not working in shared hosting. it's requied for dedicated server.

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks fine but if you can check the [attributes](http://johndyer.name/retreiving-the-duration-of-a-wmv-in-c/) of the media Info like:

```
using WMPLib; // this file is called Interop.WMPLib.dll
WindowsMediaPlayerClass wmp = new WindowsMediaPlayerClass();
string FilePath = "yourFilePath";
IWMPMedia mediaInfo = wmp.newMedia(FilePath);

// write duration
Console.WriteLine("Duration = " + mediaInfo.duration);

// write named attributes
for (int i=0; i < mediaInfo.attributeCount; i++) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(mediaInfo.getAttributeName(i) + " = " +  mediaInfo.getItemInfo(mediaInfo.getAttributeName(i)) );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code snippet may help you guys :

```
using WMPLib;
// ...your code here...

var player = new WindowsMediaPlayer();
var clip = player.newMedia(VideoFilePath);
Console.WriteLine(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(clip.duration));
```

> and don't forget to add the reference of **`wmp.dll`** which will be
>   present in **`System32`** folder.