# Get duration from a video/audio file in a Web Application (asp.net core)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, metadata

This question is about a asp.net WEB Application and not about .net windows application. In my application I am uploading video files (mp4) using asp.net core.

I need to get metadata from this video file, but for now I am focusing on the duration of this video file.

I have created the form and in my controller I am successfully receiving an `IFormFile file` object. I can find the size the file by just calling the .length method ( `file.Length` ) but I am really struggling to get the exact date and especially the duration of this object.

How can I determine the exact date and the duration of this object?

This is my code:

```
    public async Task UploadVideos(IList<IFormFile> files)
    {
        long size = files.Sum(f => f.Length);
        Console.WriteLine("The size of all the selected files is:"+size);

        Console.WriteLine("the file name is" + files[0].FileName);


        string type = files[0].ContentType;
        if (type.Equals("video/mp4"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Indeed a mp4 format");
        }

    }
```

Comment: Are you allowed to use external libs?

Comment: Yes, definitely. I can install other nuget packages.

Comment: If you don't mind waiting I will send a solution as soon as I get home, currently at work finishing up something

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2527963/using-ffmpeg-in-net

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get video duration from mp4, wmv, flv, mov videos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10190906/how-to-get-video-duration-from-mp4-wmv-flv-mov-videos)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry for the late reply, here is how you would go about getting the duration of a video after it is uploaded,

You can use [NReco](https://www.nrecosite.com/video_info_net.aspx),the provided link has a nice little example on how to get the info of a video,

```
var ffProbe = new NReco.VideoInfo.FFProbe();
var videoInfo = ffProbe.GetMediaInfo(pathToVideoFile);
Console.WriteLine(videoInfo.FormatName);
Console.WriteLine(videoInfo.Duration);
```

The the only issue being licensing for commercial use.

The other one you can try is the [mediatoolkit](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MediaToolkit/), I have used this before and it works great, especially for the functionality that you are looking for, a simple usage would be along the lines of

```
var inputFile = new MediaFile { Filename = video_name };

        using (var engine = new Engine())
        {
            engine.GetMetadata(inputFile);   
       }
```

A sample image shows the output of calling the getmetadata method,
[image: Video Data].

MediaToolkit uses an [MIT license](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIT_License)

> All the above are wrappers of the c++ FFmpeg Library

Comment: Ohh I simply can't thank you enough. Both work fine when the files are local but when I am giving a path from url (in my case I am using azure blob Storage), only the first works. I also had to dowload the ffprobe.exe file from here (https://ffbinaries.com/downloads ) and add it in the project folder. However, I needed a lot more metadata from videos so in the end I am using Media Info ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26051273/whats-the-best-way-to-get-video-metadata-from-a-mp4-file-in-asp-net-mvc-using-c ). However, I am struggling to get it working with url and not only with local paths

Comment: I am not sure about URL's, but maybe you can check this [Github](https://github.com/fcingolani/video-metadata-api) link out, its using ffprobe.exe to get metadata from a video