Get duration from a video/audio in dotnet container services
I have created the api in my controller I am successfully receiving an IFormFile file object.
How can I receive duration and size(width and height) of video without download file to local. And I want to deploy in inside docker container base on Linux.

You can use mediatoolkit nuget to get the metadata of the video file, refer answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/51601552/14973743

If that doesn't work out, see the alternative here https://stackoverflow.com/a/58069583/14973743, which uses ffmpeg, see the comments on that answer..since you need the binaries. It is supported for windows and Linux.
