# How to Access NTP or Other Timestamp Data in HTML5 Video

Tags: html, video, timestamp

Do any HTML5 video formats even store this metadata within the video file?  If so, how would I access it?  I'm looking to do something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/42513894/3757890 but syncing video with NTP timestamp (or other timestamp) data.  I realize that some of the timestamps may be in some layer of the stream that doesn't wind up in the saved video file.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the actual timeframes are ever recorded in actual time, i don't think that's even possible. The timeframes start from zero.

There can be a metadata timestamp in the video, however, that represents the time the video was recorded. The metadata depends on the video container format, i.e. MP4 can have extensive metadata.

There is some discussion on how to extract the metadata in some languages here:
[how do i find the date a video (.AVI .MP4) was actually recorded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3104641/how-do-i-find-the-date-a-video-avi-mp4-was-actually-recorded)

Comment: Ok, I think it could work if I had the time that each video actually starts (like a clapperboard), so that I could use that to sync them when they begin. Thank you!